# A SQL case statement or two

Tags: sql, case

I have a `SELECT` statement that pulls these two different product strips. When I delete one of them from the website and rerun my statement I still have two rows, the first column has the `ARMCODE` twice (two results) and the second column has the description for the first but then no description for the second (because it has been deleted).

Problem is it's still showing two results in SQL studio with the `ARMCODE`.

If there is a `a.CODE_`,`a.strips` from intake it needs to show, if there is an `A.ARMCODE` and `B.DESCRIPTION` it needs to show. If there is only `A.ARMCODE` and `B.DESCRIPTION` and the other has been deleted why is it still showing two results with `a.CODE_` being the second result and an empty a.strips.

```
select a.ARMCODE,
       b.DESCRIPTION_
  from ARE.AAS.REORDER a
  left outer join ARE.AAS.PTDME b on a.PTCODE=b.CODE_
 where a.ARMCODE = 'ADSMANZS03'
   and b.MEDICAREID ='A4253'

union all

select a.CODE_,a.strips
  from event.dbo.intake a 
 where a.CODE_ = 'ADSMANZS03'
```

[image: Strips and description, two different products, same patient]

[image: When i delete strips, still showing two results with empty description]

[image: my case statement returning nothing]

I started on a new statement using case and am now using some nested joins:

```
select case when b.ARMCODE is null then a.strips
       end
  from (select *
          from ev.dbo.intake a
         where a.CODE_ = 'ADSMANZS03') a
left outer join(select a.ARMCODE,
                       b.DESCRIPTION_
                  from ARE.AAS.REORDER a
                  left outer join ARE.AAS.PTDME b on a.PTCODE=b.CODE_
                 where a.ARMCODE = 'ADSMANZS03'
                   and b.MEDICAREID ='A4253') b on a.CODE_=b.ARMCODE
```

I'm not getting any rows or columns and it's returning (no column name) and inside NULL

Hope that is not too confusing. Thanks in advance.

**IMAGE 1** Strips and description, two different products, same patient

**IMAGE 2** When i delete strips, still showing two results with empty description, should not show a second result.

**IMAGE 3** case statement

Comment: case when b.armcode is null then a.strips ELSE (something else) end

Comment: Strips and Description are the same thing just in two different tables. If a patient has a product in strips and description it should show both or all (however many there are), if they only have a product in strips than only show the patient id and strips.

Comment: I've read your question twice but don't quite get it.  Could you clarify with example data, or see if you can reproduce it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: I'll post pics of the data being returned, thank you for following with me.

Comment: Updated, show all if there is multiple or only show one or the other if there is only one table populated with data. Maybe I should use an isnull statement? I figured a case statement might work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an fyi so this question can be closed. I used coalesce to determine what i needed.

```
select
coalesce(b.DESCRIPTION_,a.strips)
from(
select
*
from ev.dbo.intake a
where a.CODE_ = 'ADSMANZS03'
)a
left outer join(
select
a.ARMCODE,
b.DESCRIPTION_
from ARE.AAS.REORDER a
left outer join ARE.AAS.PTDME b on a.PTCODE=b.CODE_
where a.ARMCODE = 'ADSMANZS03'
and b.MEDICAREID ='A4253'
)b on a.CODE_=b.ARMCODE
```

COALESCE (Transact-SQL)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Sorry if the question was so confusing at first.